# How do I return the default record type for an object, for any given user?

Tags: types, salesforce, apex-code, custom-object

I have a custom object into which I want to add a new item and assign ownership of it to a user, which has been input via user input.  The record type does not default to the appropriate value, based on ownership, so I need to return the default record type for the specified user, so I can create my item correctly.

I can get the default record type for the object easily enough, but how do I get it for any user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default record type is only defined at the profile (and therefore user) level, not for the whole org. So, whichever user is describing the object will see their own `defaultRecordTypeMapping` defined for their Profile. For example, if User A executes this code in Apex:

```
for (Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo : Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()) {
  if (rtInfo.isDefaultRecordTypeMapping()) {
    System.debug(rtInfo);
  }
}
```

The default record type for User A will be printed. If User B were to run the same code and was assigned to a different profile with a different default record type, that user's default record type would be printed.

The same is true through the API with `describeSObject()` for SOAP or `/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/:object/describe` for REST.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, yes you're right.  How do I return User B's default record type, if I am running in the context of User A?  I'm creating records and assigning ownership to multiple users, I want to ensure that those records have the correct record type.

Comment: It is a bit hacky, but the Metadata API has this info. If you retrieve a [`package.xml` that contains the `RecordType`s and `Profile`s you care about](https://gist.github.com/ryanbrainard/5162723#file-package-xml), it will return the [cross-product mappings](https://gist.github.com/ryanbrainard/5162723#file-admin-profile) of the two. Of course you'd have to make this SOAP call out (good luck) and then parse the result. If the record types aren't changing a lot, you could do this once manually and then parse and reuse the metadata for all your inserts. See the links for examples.

Comment: Shameless plug, but if you want to see the retrieve result without having to setup a Metadata API client, you can login into [workbench.developerforce.com](https://workbench.developerforce.com), Migration | Retrieve, and provide a `package.xml` similar to [this one](https://gist.github.com/ryanbrainard/5162723#file-package-xml) (but customized for your org's record types and profiles you care about) as the Unpackaged Manifest (ignore Package Names). Go through the steps, download the file, unzip it, and look in the `profiles` directory. A lot of steps, but only way I know how to get this info.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That's as good a solution as is possible, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could get `recordId` by developer name, see [release info](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_developer_name.htm)

Try to use this instead

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Master');
```